# Parse unable to upload images due to image file size

Tags: image, swift, parse-platform, image-uploading, image-size

I'm having a problem uploading images to Parse. I believe the problem might be related to the image file size, but according to this link

https://parse.com/questions/file-size-limit-in-uploads

each file can be up to 10MB. I can successfully upload 2 images where each image is 1.7MB, but the call stalls forever as soon as I try to upload 2 images greater than 2 MB each. The app does not crash it just keeps loading indefinitely even after waiting 5 minutes for the images to load. The "Post" object is saved fine, but the images aren't being saved.

I've included the relevant code for uploading the images to parse below. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? Does it have to do with the fact that I'm saving the images to class called "Images" and then saving that PFObject in a list with the other images and then saving that list of images as a column in the "Post" class? I wanted to be able to directly access the images tied to this post without having to make an extra API call to retrieve the images associated to a post. Please let me know if any of this is unclear.

```
var post = PFObject(className: "Post")
post["caption"] = captionTextField.text
post["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()

post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if success == false {
            println("failed 1")

            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        } else {

            let imageOneData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageOne)

            let imageOneFile = PFFile(name: "imageOne.png", data: imageOneData)

            let imageTwoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageTwo)

            let imageTwoFile = PFFile(name: "imageTwo.png", data: imageTwoData)                

            var images: [PFFile] = [imageOneFile, imageTwoFile]

            var finishedUploads = 0

            var listOfImages : [PFObject] = []

            for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++ {
                var postImage = PFObject(className: "Images")
                postImage["image"] = images[i]
                postImage["postId"] = post.objectId
                postImage["likes"] = 0

                postImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in


                    finishedUploads++

                    if success == false {
                        println("failed 3")
                    } else {
                        println("success 3")

                        println(postImage.objectId)


                        listOfImages.append(postImage)

                        if finishedUploads == images.count {


                            post["listOfImages"] = listOfImages

                            post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                                if success == false {
                                    println("failed 10")
                                } else {
                                    println("success 10")

                                    var storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                                    if let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as? UINavigationController {
                                        self.presentViewController(tabViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    } else {
                                        println("What should I do here?")
                                    }
                                }

                                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: There is no error message. The activityIndicator just keeps animating forever

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was how I was representing the Image data. It should be

```
let imageOneData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageOne, 0.5)
```

not

```
let imageOneData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageOne)
```

After I uploaded the image data to Parse using UIImagePNGRepresentation, the image file sizes grew to 3 times their original size. I was able to successfully uploaded much larger images (up to 10MB as the documentation describes) using UIImageJPEGRepresentation.